# Joining two tables and query them

Tags: mysql

I want to select the name and date of birth of all living artists who have `value` more than 50. My tables are `artist` and `picture` and I wrote this SQL statement but it is not giving me the desired result. Please advise.

```
SELECT name, dateOfBirth
FROM artist 
    JOIN exhibitions.picture
        ON exhibitions.picture.name
WHERE exhibitions.picture.value = '50'
    AND artist.dayOfDeath is NULL;
```

Comment: Is `value` a character type?  Does it contain non-numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that value is a numeric data type:

```
SELECT 
    A.name
    , A.dateOfBirth

FROM
    artist A
    JOIN exhibitions.picture P
        ON A.name = P.name

WHERE
    P.Value > 50
    AND A.dayOfDeath is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use >50

```
SELECT artist.name, artist.dateOfBirth 
FROM artist JOIN exhibitions.picture 
              ON artist.name=exhibitions.picture.name 
WHERE exhibitions.picture.value>='50'
  AND artist.dayOfDeath is NULL;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1052. Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Keep alias name  like  table name in front of column name  like  exhibitions.picture.name   from which table name u want. Give full table structure fields we will give you query

Comment: @kenny its because whenever you join two or more tables it may contain same column name on each tables ,so whenever you specify column name always reference column names as   <tablename.columnname> so it will tell the query engine to take correct column from the right table (So there is no ambiguity)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT name, dateOfBirth
FROM artist 
    JOIN exhibitions.picture
        ON exhibitions.picture.name
WHERE exhibitions.picture.value >'50'
    AND artist.dayOfDeath is NULL;
```

By this query, you will get only more than 50yrs living artists.
Please use greater than condition for correct results.

Comment: If `value` is a CHAR column, then the comparisons will not yield wanted results because the order used is lexicographic. `'9' > '50'` is true for example.

Comment: The `ON` condition seems erroneous as well.